# Copy files where lastwritetime -ge 3/26/2010 9:00pm with Powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0, get-childitem

I need to copy files in one directory to another directory where the lastwritetime is greater than or equal to 3/26/2010 9:00pm.  I'm using:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\pstest\hlstore\folder1\data | where-object {$i.lastwritetime -ge “3/26/2010 9:00 PM”} | Copy-Item -destination c:\pstest\hlstore2\folder1\data
```

But nothing happens...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Emo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\pstest\hlstore\folder1\data | where-object {$_.lastwritetime -ge "3/26/2010 9:00 PM"} | Copy-Item -destination c:\pstest\hlstore2\folder1\data
```

The name of the "it" variable in `where-object` is `$_`, not `$i`.

Also, if you're using these quotes `“”` instead of `""`, I think it would also fail.

Comment: Perfect!  That was it!  Thanks so much Martinho